# Convergence of a function

Tags: sequences-and-series

if $\left(a_n\right)$ is a sequence in $\left(0,1\right),$ show that $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k \rightarrow 0$ if and only if $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k^2 \rightarrow 0$.

The latter summation's terms are smaller than the former but greater than 0. So by sandwich theorem I had established former's convergence imply latter's convergence.

How do I prove the other part?

Comment: Hint: Cauchy-Schwartz.

Comment: The series converge to zero??? Each term $a_n$ is non negative, is the summand is non negative and is zero iff all terms are zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $\frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2\to 0$, apply Cauchy Schwarz to get $$0\leq \frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n a_k \leq \frac 1n \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2}\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n 1} = \sqrt{\frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2} $$

and conclude by squeezing.

Comment: Error at the beginning. Also you destroyed my comment.

Comment: @zhw Where is the error bro?

Comment: @RakeshBhatt  It's in the first answer, now edited.

Comment: @Gabriel won't we need the fact that $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence in $\left(0,1\right)$. Is that true in general?

Comment: @RakeshBhatt $0\leq \frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ doesn't hold out of thin air.